# Заполнение данными gridview из sqlite

Tags: sqlite3, android

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отоброзить данные в gridview. Данные из базы я беру вот так:

```
mDbHelper = new SqlDB(this);   
SQLiteDatabase db2 = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor Cursor1 = db2.rawQuery("select * from schet;", null); 
startManagingCursor(Cursor1);
```

Comment: "Весь" интернет просмотрел, никак не могу найти, как даные можно отобразить. У меня задача стоит отобразить данные из базы, выделить ее и при необходимости отредактировать запись, может быть есть люди, которые помогут.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
// ...

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    R.layout.some,
    Cursor1,
    new String[] {"string", ...},
    new int[] {"id", ...}
);

adapter.setViewBinder(new SomeBinder());
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```